# Docker, laravel-websockets, ошибка "Failed to connect to Pusher"

Tags: docker, websocket

Разворачиваю проект laravel с пакетом beyondcode/laravel-websockets с помощью Docker. Проблема в том что в WebSockets Dashboard подключение проходит успешно. Но при попытке отправить broadcast событие возникает ошибка "Failed to connect to Pusher". Не могу понять в чем дело. Поиск в google результатов не дал.

Laravel v8.83.14

Docker Desktop + WSL 2 + Ubuntu 20.04

*Когда я разворачиваю с помощью OpenServer и запускаю `php artisan websockets:serve` все хорошо работает. Проблема именно в настройки Docker'a*

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  site:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
      args:
        - UID=${UID:-1000}
        - GID=${GID:-1000}
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - php
      - redis
      - mysql
      - mailhog
      - supervisor
      - websocket
    networks:
      - laravel
  
  ....


  php:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
      args:
        - UID=${UID:-1000}
        - GID=${GID:-1000}
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
      - ./dockerfiles/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - laravel

  ....

  websocket:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
      args:
        - UID=${UID:-1000}
        - GID=${GID:-1000}
    container_name: websocket
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    ports:
      - "6001:6001"
    expose:
      - "6001"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    command: php artisan websockets:serve
    networks:
      - laravel
```

**php.dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.0.7-fpm-alpine3.13

ARG UID
ARG GID

ENV UID=${UID}
ENV GID=${GID}

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html

# MacOS staff group's gid is 20, so is the dialout group in alpine linux. We're not using it, let's just remove it.
RUN delgroup dialout

RUN addgroup -g ${GID} --system laravel
RUN adduser -G laravel --system -D -s /bin/sh -u ${UID} laravel

RUN sed -i "s/user = www-data/user = laravel/g" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
RUN sed -i "s/group = www-data/group = laravel/g" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
RUN echo "php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on" >> /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/redis \
    && curl -L https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/5.3.4.tar.gz | tar xvz -C /usr/src/php/ext/redis --strip 1 \
    && echo 'redis' >> /usr/src/php-available-exts \
    && docker-php-ext-install redis

CMD ["php-fpm", "-y", "/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf", "-R"]
```

**nginx.dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

ARG UID
ARG GID

ENV UID=${UID}
ENV GID=${GID}

# MacOS staff group's gid is 20, so is the dialout group in alpine linux. We're not using it, let's just remove it.
RUN delgroup dialout

RUN addgroup -g ${GID} --system laravel
RUN adduser -G laravel --system -D -s /bin/sh -u ${UID} laravel
RUN sed -i "s/user  nginx/user laravel/g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ADD ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
```

**nginx config**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

**.env**

```
APP_URL=http://localhost

...

BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

...

PUSHER_APP_ID=local
PUSHER_APP_KEY=local
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=local
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

**broadcasting.php**

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        //Только при разработке
        'encrypted' => false,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 6001,
        'scheme' => 'http',
        'useTLS' => false,
        'curl_options' => [
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) - это отдельный сервис для уведомлений, после регистрации там нужно настройки поместить в PUSHER_ переменные в .env.

Comment: Laravel WebSockets — это пакет для Laravel 5.7 и выше, который мгновенно запустит ваше приложение с помощью WebSockets! Он имеет замену Pusher API, имеет панель отладки, статистику в реальном времени и даже позволяет создавать собственные контроллеры WebSocket.
https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/pusher

Comment: Проверьте что контейнер websocket запускается как нужно. Если всё еще не получается соединиться, поставьте в 'host' значение 'websocket', либо 'host.docker.internal'.

Comment: С помощью WebSockets Dashboard (который идет с пакетом) у меня подключается подключиться к серверу.